# How do I insert entire columns into my previously created table in pgAdmin4?

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin

given 2 csv-files named students(Name, Lesson) and professors(ProfID, Name, Lesson).

with the given Code:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3) VALUES(%s, %s)', (value1, value2, value3))

cur.execute(query)
set1 = cur.fetchall()
set2 = cur.fetchone()
```

Existing tables:
ProfID, Name, Lesson

There are no existing StudentID's. How can I assign them to each Student?

How do I insert the columns in the above example (all values in the csv files, not limited to 3 values as above) into my table?
And how do I deduplicate the data for tables?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization, create a new table which keep the info of studentid and profid +lession + name id

Comment: As I said, the StudentID is not assigned yet and has to be set in the insertion process.
The tables are already set, there has to be a solution to insert those columns without creating a table for all the rows. 
There is still the Code above, which i don't know how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There might be many possible solutions but , i tried to create on my own using SQL Scripts only.

#### I created a table by using the following scripts.

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
    column_one character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_two character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_three character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    column_four character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);
```

#### For time being i inserted data manually

```
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4');
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data11', 'data11', 'data11', 'data11');
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data21', 'data21', 'data21', 'data21');
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data31', 'data31', 'data31', 'data31');
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data41', 'data41', 'data41', 'data41');
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data51', 'data51', 'data51', 'data51');
INSERT INTO public.my_table(column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four) VALUES ('data61', 'data61', 'data61', 'data61');
```

#### Then i altered table by following script

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN  column_id INTEGER;
```

#### After that i updated the column in loop

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DO $$
DECLARE 

    col_id bigint := 1 ;
    colTemp character(40);
BEGIN    
    FOR colTemp IN
        SELECT * FROM public.my_table 
    LOOP
        UPDATE my_table set column_id = col_id where column_one = colTemp;
        col_id := col_id + 1 ; 
    END LOOP;
    
END $$;
--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --rollback in case of exception
COMMIT TRANSACTION; --commit
```

#### Define primary key when changing the existing table structure

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_id);
```

#### NOTE : Please test it before using it on some test data . Please forgive me if i misinterpreted your questions/requirements. It took me very long time for finding the solution. Any kind of suggestions will be highly appreciated.

#### Edit Description : I am just trying to simplifying the problem with some enhancements :-

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN  column_id INTEGER;
```

#### changes in loop

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DO $$
DECLARE 
    col_id bigint := 1 ;
    colTemp record ;
BEGIN    
    FOR colTemp IN
        SELECT column_one, column_two, column_three, column_four
        FROM my_table
    LOOP
        UPDATE my_table set column_id = col_id where column_one = colTemp.column_one;
        col_id := col_id + 1 ; 
    END LOOP;
    
END $$;
--ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; --rollback in case of exception
COMMIT TRANSACTION; --commit
```

#### select max id from column and increment by one in seq

```
SELECT MAX(column_id) FROM my_table;
```

#### Add Constraints

```
-- select max id and add one to it in start value
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_colid_seq
START 18 
INCREMENT 1
OWNED BY my_table.column_id;

ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN column_id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_colid_seq');
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT  column_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (column_id)
```

#### SOLUTION 2 :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN  column_id INTEGER;

CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_colid_seq
START 18 
INCREMENT 1
OWNED BY my_table.column_id;

ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN column_id SET DEFAULT nextval('my_table_colid_seq');

UPDATE
    my_table
SET
    column_id = nextval('my_table_colid_seq');
```

**Note-**Before running this query randomly just run it on test and do experiments with data and tables.Please excuse the typos. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So column_one, column_two, column_three is stationary and data1, data2, data3 has to be replaced by e.g. "Name" etc.?

Comment: I dont know what 's the table structure you're using , it would be nice if you create table with some test data, run it in your end, like i did . You will be able to recognize things better in your end.

Comment: This was the basic table structure i created and i inserted data there manually and then  i added a column and created a script by which i can insert data in a loop.

Comment: We haven't worked with transaction methods yet.
Table1: Students
Table2: Professors
Table3: Lessons
Table4: Name

Referring to the "variables" There are thousands of variables in each csv-file, that needs to be inserted. How do I insert the entiere row, instead of single variables?

Comment: In above script , I just tried to demonstrate how a column can be inserted by using loop.